# How to display code "< />" as plain text in React?

Tags: reactjs, text

I want to display < /> as plain text on my react page. I tried `<code> </code>` and I have also tried using &lt &gt but it doesn't work. Does anyone know how to do it? Many thanks

Comment: Please show your attempt/s.

Answer (score 0):

You can render it as a string as follows:

```js
<p>{"</>"}</p>
```